# Threadpool in C# too slow, is there a way to speed up it? Thread.Sleep(0) and QueueUserWorkItem issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

I am using Threadpool in a C# application that need to do some CPU-intensive work. By the way it seems too slow (EDIT: it prints out debug string `"Calculating on " 
          + lSubArea.X + ":" + lSubArea.Y + " " 
          + lSubArea.Width + ":" + lSubArea.Height` only few times every 10 seconds, while I'm expecting to see that at least NUM_ROWS_GRID^2 = 16 times every few seconds), also changing MinThreads via `SetMinThreads` method. I don't know if switch to custom threads or if there's a way to speed up it. Searching on Google returns me some result but nothing works; same situation with MSDN.

Old Code follows:

```
private void StreamerRoutine()
{
   if (this._state.Area.Width == 0 && this._state.Area.Height == 0)
      this._state.Area = new Rectangle(0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

   while (this._state.WorkEnd == false)
   {
      // Ends time slice if video is off
      if (this._state.VideoOn == false)
         Thread.Sleep(0);
      else
      {
         lock(this._state.AreaSync)
         {
             Int32 lWidth = this._state.Area.Width / Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID;
             Int32 lHeight = this._state.Area.Height / Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID;
             for (Int32 lX = 0; lX + lWidth <= this._state.Area.Width; lX += lWidth)
                for (Int32 lY = 0; lY + lHeight <= this._state.Area.Height; lY += lHeight)
                   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CreateDiffFrame, (Object)new Rectangle(lX, lY, lWidth, lHeight));
         }
      }
    }
}

private void CreateDiffFrame(Object pState)
{
   Rectangle lSubArea = (Rectangle)pState;

   SmartDebug.DWL("Calculating on " 
          + lSubArea.X + ":" + lSubArea.Y + " " 
          + lSubArea.Width + ":" + lSubArea.Height);
   // TODO : calculate frame
   Thread.Sleep(0);
}
```

EDIT: CreateDiffFrame function is only a stub I used to know how many times it is called per second. It will be replaced with CPU intensive work as I define the best way to use thread in this case.

EDIT: I removed all Thread.Sleep(0); I thought it could be a way to speed up routine but it seems it could be a bottleneck.. new code follows:

EDIT: I made WorkEnd and VideoOn volatile in order to avoid cached values and so endless loop; I added also a semaphore to make every bunch of work items start after previous bunch is done.. now it is working quite well

```
private void StreamerRoutine()
    {
        if (this._state.Area.Width == 0 && this._state.Area.Height == 0)
            this._state.Area = new Rectangle(0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

        this._state.StreamingSem = new Semaphore(Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID * Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID, Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID * Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID);


        while (this._state.WorkEnd == false)
        {
            if (this._state.VideoOn == true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID * Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID; i++)
                    this._state.StreamingSem.WaitOne();

                lock(this._state.AreaSync)
                {
                    Int32 lWidth = this._state.Area.Width / Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID;
                    Int32 lHeight = this._state.Area.Height / Constants.NUM_ROWS_GRID;
                    for (Int32 lX = 0; lX + lWidth <= this._state.Area.Width; lX += lWidth)
                        for (Int32 lY = 0; lY + lHeight <= this._state.Area.Height; lY += lHeight)
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CreateDiffFrame, (Object)new Rectangle(lX, lY, lWidth, lHeight));

                }
            }
        }
    }

private void CreateDiffFrame(Object pState)
    {
        Rectangle lSubArea = (Rectangle)pState;

        SmartDebug.DWL("Calculating on " + lSubArea.X + ":" + lSubArea.Y + " " + lSubArea.Width + ":" + lSubArea.Height);
        // TODO : calculate frame
        this._state.StreamingSem.Release(1);

    }
```

Comment: Why all the sleeps?

Comment: What is "too slow"? The ThreadPool is a fairly low-overhead wrapper to System.Threading.Threads, so my guess is that it is the code within the threads of the manner in which they are queued that is causing your performance issues.

Comment: This makes no sense. You can only judge the speed with real code, not by Sleeping. And you could well have some problems, but the ThreadPool isn't one of them.

Comment: How many items are you queuing? And how many items does it manage to complete per second?

Comment: @spender "Specify zero (0) to indicate that this thread should be suspended to allow other waiting threads to execute" from [msdn] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx)
I used it to make current thread end its time slice.

Comment: @Fran I know what `sleep(0)` does, but why do you want to do that here? Since you should not have more threads than virtual cpu cores when solving a CPU intensive problem, ending a timeslice makes no sense at all. The only thing you achieve with this is reducing performance.

Comment: Why all the sleeps? That's blocking the threadpool threads rather than allowing them to be used for different jobs. It's going to be hugely inefficient and is not how the threadpool is intended to be used. I can't see how you can claim the threadpool is slow when your example code presents almost no work to be performed in the pool.

Comment: @CodeInChaos .. as I edited in OP -> CreateDiffFrame function is only a stub I used to know how many times it is called per second. It will be replaced with CPU intensive work as I define the best way to use threads in this case.

Comment: You still haven't said why you think it's "too slow". It's not like you'll need more than a few hundred items per second. And the performance decreasing `sleep`s are still in there. And why would you want to set the minimum number of threads? You don't need more threads than virtual CPUs, and the threadpool already has at least that many threads.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Sorry, I'll edit OP now.. Anyway I think it's slow because it prints out debug string `"Calculating on " 
          + lSubArea.X + ":" + lSubArea.Y + " " 
          + lSubArea.Width + ":" + lSubArea.Height` only few times every 10 seconds

Comment: Your `while` loop makes no sense either. I'm pretty sure it's not thread safe, but without the real code I can't tell you the exact mistake.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I'm sure while loop is thread safe, why are thinking it?

Comment: The costly part is not in this code if you only work only through a few items per second. This code as it stands should be able to do thousands of items per second, even with your `Sleep` calls. And many more without them.

Comment: For one it can queue items before the previous bunch was finished. Then `this._state.WorkEnd` and `this._state.VideoOn` don't get ever changed in the loop, which might be dangerous too, but probably some implicit memory barriers save you from that being an actual bug.

Comment: @CodeInChaos It is true, it can queue items before the previous bunch was finished (I'm thinking that it can somehow affect performance). About those flags they are modified in another class (Windows form) and as I remember (I can be wrong) operations on boolean are interlocked, so are thread safe..

Comment: Setting a boolean is atomic, but the associated memory barriers are too weak. But atomicity is not enough, the reading code may work on a stale cached value, unless you have a memory barrier in between. But you're lucky that your locks and sleeps provide those barriers. I wouldn't rely on these implicit memory barriers without adding at least a comment documenting where those barriers are, and which code relies on them. | If your only items are still working when a new batch arrives, they probably will work on the new batch instead, since you don't pass in a reference to immutable image data.

Comment: Your edited code may deadlock if `WorkEnd` and `VideoOn` aren't volatile. Since once both of them are false, the computer can decide both of them will stay `false` forever and enter an endless loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5741/discussion-between-francesco-and-codeinchaos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a good way to tell you exactly what's making your code slow from what I see, but there are a couple of things that stand out:

1. Thread.Sleep(0).  When you do this, you give up the rest of your timeslice from the OS, and slow down everything, because CreateDiffFrame() can't actually return until the OS scheduler comes back to it.
2. The object cast of Rectangle, which is a struct.  You incur the overhead of [boxing](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/article.php/c5883) when this happens, which isn't going to be something you'll want for truly compute-intensive operations.
3. Your calls to lock(this._state.AreaSync).  It could be that AreaSync is being locked somewhere else, too, and that could be slowing things down.
4. You may be queueing items too granularly -- if you queue very small items of work, it's likely that the overhead of putting these items in the queue one at a time could be significant as compared to the actual amount of work done.  You could also perhaps consider putting the contents of the inner loop inside the queued work item to cut down this overhead.

If this is something you're trying to do for parallel computation, have you investigated using [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) or another such framework?

Comment: Ok thanks, 1 Maybe that's the problem 2 I'll try to see if I can use a different structure, 3 I'm sure it is not locked elsewhere, 4 Probably, I am thinking perhaps I have to use Threadpool with a bigger granularity.
About PLINQ I didn't know it, now I'll take a look thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it's the Sleep at the end of CreateDiffFrame. It means each thread stays alive for at least another 10 ms, if I remember correctly. You can probably do the actual work in less than 10 ms. ThreadPool tries to optimize the usage of threads, but I think it has an upper limit to the total number of outstanding threads. So if you want to actually mimic your workload, make a tight loop that waits until the expected number of milliseconds have passed instead of a Sleep.

Anyway, I don't think using ThreadPool is the actual bottleneck, using an other threading mechanism will not speed up your code.

Comment: No, Sleep(0) will just yield the CPU. It is a bad/unnecessary idea though.

Answer (score 0):

There is known bug with the `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` method described in [KB976898](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976898/):

> After you use the ThreadPool.SetMinThreads method in the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5, threads maintained by the thread pool do not work as expected

You can download a fix to this behavior from [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=32699).